# How to install X509 certificate chain without the private key

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509

I have been given three certificates by my client:

`DigiCert Global Root CA.cer - (Root certificate)
GeoTrust RSA CA 2018.cer - (Intermediate certificate)
krapiuat_sharekhan_com.cer - (SSL certificate for my domain)`

I am expected to install all the three certificates on my Spring Boot server to enable SSL on the same.

I am using this with the embedded Tomcat server in my Spring Application and am unable to start the SSL enabled service due to errors.

My attempts are as stated below:

Attempt 1

I tried to combine all three .cer files into a single file and add it to the keystore

```
`cat krapiuat_sharekhan_com.cer  GeoTrust\ RSA\ CA\ 2018.cer  DigiCert\ Global\ Root\ CA.cer> combined_cert.cer

keytool -importcert -keystore krKeyStore.jks -file combined_cert.cer -alias krRiskRatingUAT -trustcacerts`
```

Note: The final jks file showed just one entry as trustedCertEntry

Then I added the file krKeyStore.jks in the /resource folder of my Spring app and added the following lines in my application.properties file:

```
`server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:krKeyStore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=mypassword
server.ssl.key-alias=krRiskRatingUAT`
```

The service failed to start with the exception java.io.IOException: jsse.alias_no_key_entry

---

Attempt 2

I tried to individually add the three certificates to my keystore

```
`keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file DigiCert\ Global\ Root\ CA.cer -keystore krKeyStore20.jks
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias intermediate -file GeoTrust\ RSA\ CA\ 2018.cer -keystore krKeyStore20.jks
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias krRiskRatingUAT20 -file krapiuat_sharekhan_com.cer -keystore krKeyStore20.jks`
```

Note: The final jks file now showed three entries all as trustedCertEntry

Then I added the file krKeyStore20.jks in the /resource folder of my Spring app and added the following lines in my application.properties file:

```
`server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:krKeyStore20.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=mypassword
server.ssl.key-alias=krRiskRatingUAT20`
```

But the error still persists - java.io.IOException: jsse.alias_no_key_entry

Is it always mandatory to have the key? My client is not ready to give me the private key and wants me to install the certificates without a key. Any help will be duly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply cannot create a SSL server without having the private key for the server certificate. The private key is needed to proof to the client that you are the owner of the certificate, otherwise anybody who gets access to the certificate (which is every client connecting to the server) could claim to be owner of the certificate, i.e. everybody could claim to be google.com or similar.

Comment: Thanks!! Appreciate your enlightening me on this. Am I doing the rest of the steps of adding the certificate chain correctly? So, the reason for the exception is solely the absence of the key, right?

Comment: @AneriSheth: The error message clearly says that the problem is the missing key. If everything else is correct I don't know but this is also not part of the original question. And it does not really matter as long as you don't have a key anyway.

Comment: *You simply cannot create a SSL server without having the private key for the server certificate.*  Yes, you can.  But you have to use an anonymous cipher suite that offers no protection against man-in-the-middle attacks. No certificate is used at all in that case. See [the OpenSSL Diffie-Hellman wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Diffie_Hellman#Diffie-Hellman_in_SSL.2FTLS): "**Anonymous Diffie-Hellman** uses Diffie-Hellman, but without authentication. Because the keys used in the exchange are not authenticated, the protocol is susceptible to Man-in-the-Middle attacks..."

Comment: (cont)  If you're using OpenSSL, you'd probably have to compile your own OpenSSL implementation to use such a cipher suite, though, as I'm pretty sure anonymous cipher suites are not only not enabled by default, they're not even compiled and therefore not implemented in "normal" OpenSSL installations.

Comment: @AndrewHenle:  I think it should be clear from the question that the OP wants to use a certificate. And if you want to use a certificate (which you need to if you want to interact with HTTPS in browsers) then you also need a private key for this certificate. If you don't use a certificate (which you can do with anon DH, PSK, SRP ...) then you of course also don't need a private key for a certificate which does not exist.